# React setState reading as undefined after filtering through API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate, jsonapi-resources

I'm trying to filter an api response in React to certain news items, but when I call the setState function my console is throwing the error that it cannot setState of property undefined. I'm new to React so excuse me if this is an obvious fix.

```
    class LeagueTables extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super();
            this.state = {
                sportsNewsFiltered: []
            };
            this.mountNews = this.mountNews.bind(this);
        }
        mountNews() {
            var tempArr = [];
            var urlNews =
                "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc- 
                  sport&apiKey=" + SECRETS.API_KEY;
            var reqNews = new Request(urlNews);
            fetch(reqNews)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(function(json) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < json.articles.length; i++) {
                        if (json.articles[i].url.includes("football")) {
                            tempArr.push(json.articles[i]);
                         }
                    }
                })
                .then(function() {
                        this.setState({
                        sportsNewsFiltered: tempArr
                    });
                });
         }
        componentDidMount() {
            this.mountNews();
        }
```

Comment: `this` in your second and third `then` callbacks isn't a reference to your component anymore, because you're using traditional (`function`) functions. If you use arrow functions consistently (your first `then` handler is one, but the second two aren't), those arrow functions will close over `this` and it will refer to your component instance.

Comment: Side note: You're not checking that the request succeeded. You're not alone, so many people fail to check that I wrote up the problem in a [post on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html). Check `.ok` (or `.status`).

Comment: That's really helpful, thank you so much! It's nice to understand why instead of just doing. Thanks again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are loosing this context so Change it to arrow function

```
  .then(() => {
                    this.setState({
                    sportsNewsFiltered: tempArr
                });
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

So this in your set state is referring to the function its in not the react class as you want, to fix this simply have:
    () =>{...}

Instead of:
    function () {...}